# Holden Commodore (1999) won't click over but everything is turned on

Tags: electrical, holden

Car not clicking over but everything is working, when the key is taken out the dashboard lights stay on and radio but the key is out

Comment: What exact model/year of Holden is your car? When you open the door after taking the key out, does everything shut off? Are there any strange indicators in your dash lights? Anything which looks like a key or a flashing key?

Comment: Hi it's a Holden commodore 1999, when the door is open everything is still on. The dashboard lights are on and the indicators still work. There isn't any key or flashing key light that pop up

Comment: Check if the battery terminals are loose or dirty.

Comment: "click over" is not standard automotive terminology. Maybe it would help if you make your question more clear.

Comment: Have you managed to get it fixed?